# Trying to make a menu like this...one

Tags: jquery, css

http://www.antisweden.no/

I love the menu and i want to be able to do it...any ideas?

Thanks[image: Here's the menu, with the sub menu]

Comment: The page doesn't seem to want to load for me right now. I'd suggest you take a screenshot and cut just the section you want. That might make it easier for others because some people don't like to have to visit another site just to find what you are talking about. Also it might be good to explain what you have tried or are thinking of trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a bit of a partial solution here until I have some more time to work on it later tonight.
http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/jVDUX/

Will probably need to set a timeout on the mouseleave event and clear it if they mouse over again.

---

Updated example

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/jVDUX/5/

```
$(function() {

var timeout;
var menucontent = $("#menucontent");
$('#menu').mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    menucontent.animate({
        marginLeft: '-550px'
    }, 1000);
});

menucontent.mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});

menucontent.mouseleave(function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        menucontent.animate({
            marginLeft: '50px'
        }, 1000);
    }, 3000);
});

});
```

html

```
<div id="body">
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menucontent">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#content1">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#content2">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#content3">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#content4">Link4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#content5">Link5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#content6">Link6</a></li>            
        </ul>        
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#body {
   height:800px;
   width:600px;   
   border:1px solid black;
   overflow:hidden;
}

#menu {
   position:relative;
   top: 100px;   
   float:right;
   background-color:black;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   color:white;
}

#menucontent {
   width:550px;
   height:100%;
   margin-left:700px;
   background-color:black;
}

#menucontent ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height:100%;
   float: left;}

#menucontent ul li{
   display: inline;
   height:100%;
}

#menucontent ul li a{
   color:white;
   float: left;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 10px 10px;
   height:30px;
}

#menucontent ul li a:visited{}

#menucontent ul li a:hover {
   background-color:#0b75b2;
}
```

Comment: That's just sensational...take my hat off to you for this.

Comment: Thanks :) There is a bit more work to do yet but since I'm at work I will have to look at that later.

Answer (score 3):

"View Source" is always a good place to start.  You could also use a tool like FireBug or the IE 8+ Developer Tools to see how the site does what it does.

Comment: @Blender: That too. Sorry, I'm not familiar with Chrome and its tools.

Comment: Exactly like Firebug, only Chromy.

Comment: Haha, love the mention of IE8+ Developer tools yet you failed to mention the **god** chrome. ;)